# Google Chart Tooltip Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, google-visualization, linechart

I have created a Google Line Chart and I am trying to change my tooltip options. The tooltip will display strings such as "Apr 1991 : \n 295,3131". I know you can use the textstyle property and set the text to bold. However, is there a way you can apply it to just a portion of the string. For instance, is there some way I can my my tooltip appear like this?

Apr 1991

**295, 3131**

Just wondering if I am able to set bold to true on just a portion of the string. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable HTML in your tooltips, which will allow you to bold whatever you like.  See the [documentation on using HTML tooltips](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#enabling_html_tooltip).